# What is simpler way to find projection of a point on a plane?

Tags: regions, geometry, projection

This is my code to find the coordinate of projection of the point `pA = {2, 3, 5}` on the plane `-284 + 14  x + 2  y + 5 z == 0`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pA = {2, 3, 5};
myP = -284 + 14 x + 2 y + 5 z;
{x, y, z} /. 
 Solve[{x == pA[[1]] + Coefficient[myP, x] t, 
   y == pA[[2]] + Coefficient[myP, y] t, 
   z == pA[[3]] + Coefficient[myP, z] t, myP == 0}, {x, y, z, t}, Reals]
```

> {{16, 5, 10}}

What is simpler way to find the projection of a point on a plane?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RegionNearest[ImplicitRegion[myP == 0, {x, y, z}]]@pA
```

> `{16, 5, 10}`

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pA = {2, 3, 5};
myP = -284 + 14 x + 2 y + 5 z;
```

---

The normal vector to the plane is:

```
Coefficient[myP, {x, y, z}]
```

> {14, 2, 5}

The line that passes through the point `pA` and is parallel to the normal vector is given by:

```
line = Coefficient[myP, {x, y, z}] t + pA
```

{2 + 14 t, 3 + 2 t, 5 + 5 t}

---

For Mathematica processing, convert to rules:

```
pline = Thread[{x, y, z} -> line]
```

> {x -> 2 + 14 t, y -> 3 + 2 t, z -> 5 + 5 t}

---

To find where the parametric line intersects the plane (i.e., closest point), solve for `t`:

```
sol = First@(myP == 0 /. pline // Solve[#, t] &)

{t -> 1}
```

---

```
res = line /. sol
```

> {16, 5, 10}

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. My way is similar to your way.