# How can I find distance from a point to a straight line by using projection of the point to the line?

Tags: regions, geometry, distance

I have a point `A(1,2,3)` and a line having parametric equation `x = 1 + 2t, y = 3t, z = -4+6t`. I want to find distance from `A` to the line. I tried with anotther way.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pA = {1, -2, -3};
f[t_] = {1 + 2 t, 3 t, -4 + 6 t};
pB = f[1];
pC = f[2];
d = InfiniteLine[pB, pC];
RegionDistance[d, pA]
```

> Sqrt[14/5]

How can I find projection `pH` of the point `A` to the line and use `EuclideanDistance[pA, pH]`?

Comment: RegionNearest ?

Comment: …Isn't this essentially the same as your previous question?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300322/1871 Or you're not aware of `ParametricRegion`?

Comment: `Clear[d];
pA = {1, -2, -3};
f[t_] = {1 + 2  t, 3  t, -4 + 6  t};
pB = f[1];
pC = f[2];
d = InfiniteLine[{pB, pC}];
RegionDistance[d, pA];
{EuclideanDistance[RegionNearest[d]@pA, pA], 
 EuclideanDistance[RegionNearest[ParametricRegion[f[t], {t}]]@pA, pA]}` , We note that  `d = InfiniteLine[{pB, pC}]` or `d = InfiniteLine[pB, pC-pB]` instead of `d = InfiniteLine[pB, pC]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[t_] := {1 + 2 t, 3 t, -4 + 6 t};
```

This line passes through `{1, 0, -4}`, but this information is not useful at this point. The direction of this line is:

```
dir = Coefficient[f[t], t] (* {2, 3, 6} *)
```

The vector from `f[t]` to `pA` is `f[t]-pA` and at the point of minimum distance the dot product of these vectors should be zero.

```
sol = (f[t] - pA) . dir == 0 // Solve[#, t] & // First
```

> {t -> 0}

```
nearestpt = f[t] /. sol  (* {1, 0, -4} *)

EuclideanDistance[nearestpt, pA]
```

> Sqrt[5]

---

Using @xzczd's suggestion in the comment:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[f[t], t] (* check RegionQ[reg] *)

{RegionNearest[reg, pA], RegionDistance[reg, pA]}
```

> {{1, 0, -4}, Sqrt[5]}

---

Regarding your attempt:

Use an extra set of braces in your `Line` command.

```
pB = f[0];
pC = f[1];
d = InfiniteLine[{pB, pC}]
RegionDistance[d, pA]
```

> Sqrt[5]

---

If you want to use `Projection`:

```
Projection[f[t] - pA, dir] == {0, 0, 0} // Solve[#, t] & // First
```

> {t -> 0}

from which the same result follows.